# Subclassing UITableViewCell and connecting outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working in Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

I have a number of table view cell prototypes where the cells are very similar, but there are enough differences where I want to make a subclass of UITableviewCell to hold all the similar outlets and the basic initialization, but then create a few classes which subclass off of the new class.

Question is, how do I get the outlets for these cells all connected to the outlets in the base class?

I can do this for the first cell, but then IB sees those outlets as connected, and won't let me connect them from the next subclassed cell.

I copied the first prototyped cell and pasted it in, then changed it's class to the second type.  This still showed the outlets connected, and this seems to work, however, an action for a button in the second cell is not working.

What's the trick to getting all the different subclassed cells to have their outlets and actions connected to the base cell class?

Comment: Ok, well, not sure what happened the first time.  I posted this because in my second subclassed cell, I attempted to control-drag from my label to the existing @IBOutlet statement in my base class, and it didn't work, i.e.it did not either highlight an existing outlet, or give the dialog to create a new one.  I just tried it again, and it worked, and runs fine.  So I'm not sure what I was doing wrong the first time, but it seems to be working.  Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at an answer this, this was just some form of operator error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different classes for different cell then take objects of those classes and by using them you will be able to use your different cell's label,button etc

```
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourSubClass1

let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourSubClass2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the outlets of the second cell and connect them again to the subclass outlet properties after changing the second class type.

If you don't remove the outlets, it will still refer to the outlets of the first cell and that won't work.